# OCaml Addable Numbers

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, monads

I'm learning OCaml, from a little bit of Haskell that I studied for my thesis, and I'm wondering if there is a similar mechanism (type classes) to expresses that two numbers are addable (like a generic for int, float, string, etc). I know that in OCaml type classes don't exist but I'm wondering for similar mechanism to express the same thing

I'm trying to make a module type that have the common "method" add, but without success.

```
module type Addable = sig
type t
  val add : t -> t -> t 
  val zero : t
  val one : t
end

module Addable_int : Addable with type t = int = struct
  type t = int
  let add a b = a + b
  let zero = 0
  let one = 1
end

module Addable_float : Addable with type t = float = struct
  type t = float
  let add a b = a +. b
  let zero = 0.
  let one = 1.
end

let rec sum (type a) (module A : Addable with type t = a) =
  match l with
  | [] -> A.zero
  | x::l -> A.add x (sum (module A) l)
```

Update: The function sum give an error: "This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type a
The type constructor a would escape its scope"

Update-Update:

```
module type NumberType = sig
type t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val zero : t
  val one : t
end

module IntNumber : NumberType with type t = int = struct
  type t = int
  let add x y = x + y
  let zero = 0
  let one = 1
end

module FloatNumber : NumberType with type t = float = struct
  type t = float
  let add x y = x +. y
  let zero = 0.0
  let one = 1.0
end

module Addbl (M: NumberType) = struct
  type t = M.t
  let add x y = M.add x y
  let zero = M.zero
  let one = M.one
end

let rec sum : type a. (module NumberType with type t = a) -> a list -> a = 
  fun (module M) l ->
    match l with
    | [] -> M.zero
    | x::t -> M.add x (sum (module M) t)

let () = 
  let xs = [1.;2.;3.] in
  let _ = print_float @@ sum (module FloatNumber) xs in
  let _ = print_string "\n" in
  let xsi = [1;2;3;4] in
  print_int @@ sum (module IntNumber) xsi
```

This code work and the sum function is generalized. I don't know if there is a way to eliminate the need to pass (module IntNumber) or (module FloatNumber) in the sum function, to abstract this behaviour

Comment: We can't help you fix your attempt if you don't show it to us.

Comment: Sorry, i've now uploaded my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OCaml does not have type classes.

But, consider the [`Float`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Float.html) and [`Int`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Int.html) modules both implement several common functions, like `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div`, etc.

They also both have a type `t` and implement these functions in terms of `t`. This allows for a functor to abstract out these behaviors and work much the same way.

```
# module type NumberType = sig
        type t
    val add : t -> t -> t
    val sub : t -> t -> t
    val mul : t -> t -> t
    val div : t -> t -> t
  end

  module Math (N : NumberType) = struct
    type t = N.t
    let ( + ) = N.add
    let ( - ) = N.sub
    let ( * ) = N.mul
    let ( / ) = N.div
  end;;
module type NumberType =
  sig
    type t
    val add : t -> t -> t
    val sub : t -> t -> t
    val mul : t -> t -> t
    val div : t -> t -> t
  end
module Math :
  functor (N : NumberType) ->
    sig
      type t = N.t
      val ( + ) : t -> t -> t
      val ( - ) : t -> t -> t
      val ( * ) : t -> t -> t
      val ( / ) : t -> t -> t
    end
# let open Math (Int) in
  45 + 67;;
- : int = 112
# let open Math (Float) in
  45.6 + 87.2;;
- : float = 132.8
```

An example with an `Addable` type using functors:

```
# module type Addable = sig
    type t
    val nil : t
    val add : t -> t -> t
  end;;
module type Addable =
  sig type t val nil : t val add : t -> t -> t end
# module SumList (A : Addable) = struct
    type t = A.t
    let sum_list = List.fold_left A.add A.nil
  end;;
module SumList :
  functor (A : Addable) ->
    sig type t = A.t val sum_list : t list -> t end
# let open SumList (struct include Int let nil = 0 end) in
  sum_list [1; 2; 3; 4];;
- : int = 10
# let open SumList (struct 
    include String 
    let nil = "" 
    let add = (^) 
  end) in
  sum_list ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"];;
- : string = "foobarbaz"
```

You might also use the same `Addable` module signature with first class modules to avoid the need for the functors, allowing one function to sum lists of different types.

```
# let sum_list 
      (type a) 
      (module A : Addable with type t = a) 
      (lst : a list) = 
    List.fold_left A.add A.nil lst;;
val sum_list : (module Addable with type t = 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
# module IntAdd = struct
    type t = int
    let nil = 0
    let add = (+)
  end;;
module IntAdd : sig type t = int val nil : t val add : t -> t -> t end
# module StringAdd = struct
    type t = string
    let nil = ""
    let add = (^)
  end;;
module StringAdd : sig type t = string val nil : t val add : t -> t -> t end
# module FloatAdd = struct
    type t = float
    let nil = 0. 
    let add = (+.)
  end;;
module FloatAdd : sig type t = float val nil : t val add : t -> t -> t end
# sum_list (module IntAdd) [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
- : int = 15
# sum_list (module StringAdd) ["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"; "5"];;
- : string = "12345"
# sum_list (module FloatAdd) [1.; 2.; 3.; 4.; 5.];;
- : float = 15.
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but give me error. Perhaps i was not clear to my intent. Now i've uploaded the code. The goal is to express like Any types that "implements" the Addable can be used in generic functions that take an Addable parameter. Or in the case of my example, a List of Addable that can be used

Comment: I have modified to show the module signature given a name `NumberType`. Any module implementing that signature (possibly more) can be passed to that functor or some other functor whereby you get a whole module of functions which work on the type that module describes.

Comment: But i do not comprehend how can i define a list of these, and use them in a function. I've tried but without success